# Check whether the partition key exists in the collection for CosmosDB

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any way to check whether the partition key exists within a collection for CosmosDB?

For example, the available partition keys are states in the US such as WA, NY, MA, etc.. Is there any SQL statement for CosmosDB to check whether `NY` is part of the partition key in the collection?

Let's say if it is impossible, is there any way to return a list of partition keys in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT myColl.partitionKey FROM myColl
```

which will return the unique values of the partitionKey. Replace partition key with what you have as a partitionKey in your collection

Comment: hmm, it actually doesn't return anything for me when my collection has some partition keys.. not sure why..

Comment: you need to replace your partition key instead of partitionKey

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the need for a cross partition query ([which gets more important as you manage more data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container#avoiding-cross-partition-queries)), you could do a SELECT COUNT query for all documents that have the value of the partition key you're checking. Check if count is greater than 0 and return the value.

Here's a query that fits your example where your partition key is `/state`:

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) > 0
FROM c
WHERE c.state = "NY"
```